# Update existing shelve file in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, shelveset

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 is it possible to update just one file that's inside a Shelveset?

I submitted my code to the Team Explorer Shelveset, however I changed a couple of lines and want to update just the one file. Is there a way to achieve this or do I have to abandon the Shelveset and resubmit a new one?